# Docker: keep python packages consistent

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose

I want to run docker in my homelab for any python related projects.
To save diskspace and keep installed python packages across dockers consistent, I am looking for a way to share the installed python packages across the different services.

Services:

- Juypterlab (to create python scripts)
- Kestra (for automated execution of scripts)
- Couple of Flask apps

Expectation:
If I install `pip install pandas` in Jupyterlab, this package will also be available immediately in the Kestra container

I am quite new to docker and docker-compose.

Comment: make a common base image having all package and use it for all docker images

Answer (score 0):

You can use Docker [Volumes](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/)

> Volumes can be more safely shared among multiple containers.

You can install your libraries on Volume.

You can define Volumes on `dockerfile`, `docker-compose` file or on `cli`

But to share volumes, you should define named volumes.

You can do so using `cli` or `docker-compose` file.

cli

```bash
docker volume create --name shared-volume
docker run -d --name container1 -v shared-volume:/path/in/container1 my-image1
docker run -d --name container2 -v shared-volume:/path/in/container2 my-image2
```

docker-compose file

```
services:
 service1:
    image: my-image1
    volumes:
      - shared-volume:/path/in/container1
 service2:
    image: my-image2
    volumes:
      - shared-volume:/path/in/container2
volumes:
 shared-volume
```

A named volume is declared for the path /path/in/container(1/2).
Docker will create a volume, named shared-volume, (folder on your pc)  and mount it to /path/in/container(1/2) inside the container. This means that any data written to /path/in/container(1/2) inside the container will be stored in the volume and persist even after the container is stopped or removed.

[image: docker volume]
*image from docker docs [link](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/)*

Beware containers might overwrite each other's data stored on the volume.

Comment: Unclear how this would work for Python packages. Especially compiled ones

Comment: python libraries are installed on the Volume